# Get unix file type with Python os module

Tags: python, unix, operating-system

I would like to get the unix file type of a file specified by path (find out whether it is a regular file, a named pipe, a block device, ...)

I found in the docs `os.stat(path).st_type` but in Python 3.6, this seems not to work.

Another approach is to use `os.DirEntry` objects (e. g. by `os.listdir(path)`), but there are only methods `is_dir()`, `is_file()` and `is_symlink()`.

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3.6 has `pathlib` and its `Path` objects have methods:

- `is_dir()`
- `is_file()`
- `is_symlink()`
- `is_socket()`
- `is_fifo()`
- `is_block_device()`
- `is_char_device()`

`pathlib` takes a bit to get used to (at least for me having come to Python from C/C++ on Unix), but it is a nice library

Comment: I absolutely did not know about this one. I just opened the docs and it looks nice, thank you. Just to save a google search for the others: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: It is also available as an installable package for Python 2. I have published [`ruamel.std.pathlib`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.std.pathlib) on PyPI, which has a few extensions on `Path`, and a"PathLibConversionHelper" class that can assist in transitioning.

Answer (score 3):

You use the [`stat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stat.html) module to interpret the result of `os.stat(path).st_mode`.

```
>>> import os
>>> import stat
>>> stat.S_ISDIR(os.stat('/dev/null').st_mode)
False
>>> stat.S_ISCHR(os.stat('/dev/null').st_mode)
True
```

You can make a general function to return the determined type. This works for both Python 2 and 3.

```
import enum
import os
import stat

class PathType(enum.Enum):
    dir = 0  # directory
    chr = 1  # character special device file
    blk = 2  # block special device file
    reg = 3  # regular file
    fifo = 4  # FIFO (named pipe)
    lnk = 5  # symbolic link
    sock = 6  # socket
    door = 7  # door  (Py 3.4+)
    port = 8  # event port  (Py 3.4+)
    wht = 9  # whiteout (Py 3.4+)

    unknown = 10

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, path):
        if not isinstance(path, int):
            path = os.stat(path).st_mode
        for path_type in cls:
            method = getattr(stat, 'S_IS' + path_type.name.upper())
            if method and method(path):
                return path_type
        return cls.unknown

PathType.__new__ = (lambda cls, path: cls.get(path))
```

```
>>> PathType('/dev/null')
<PathType.chr: 1>
>>> PathType('/home')
<PathType.dir: 0>
```

Answer (score 0):

20 November 2020

The code supplied in the answer by 'Artyer' does not work in `python 2.7.17`, but appears to work in `python 3.6.9` except for one detail:

The call:

```
path = os.stat(path).st_mode
```

should be:

```
path = os.lstat(path).st_mode
```

Otherwise you just get the regular file that a soft link points to.

For `python 2` (and `3`), if you wish to follow this style of coding, the following is better, with some name changes for clarity:

```
import enum,os,stat
class PathTypes(enum.Enum):
  door = 0  # door       (Py 3.4+)
  port = 1  # event port (Py 3.4+)
  wht  = 2  # whiteout   (Py 3.4+)
  dir  = 3  # directory
  chr  = 4  # character special device file
  blk  = 5  # block special device file
  reg  = 6  # regular file
  fifo = 7  # FIFO (named pipe)
  lnk  = 8  # symbolic link
  sock = 9  # socket
  unimplemented = 10

def filetype(path):
  mode=os.lstat(path).st_mode # do not follow links
  for t in PathTypes:
    try: func=getattr(stat, 'S_IS' + t.name.upper())
    except AttributeError: continue
    if func(mode): return t
  return PathTypes["unimplemented"]
```

Notice the reordering that forces testing in `python 2` to consider undefined stat functions and exercise the necessary `try...except` statement.  The members are also renumbered since in `python 2`,  `enum.ENUM` apparently sorts the members by value, and this is apparently undocumented.  Since `python 2` is now not supported, bug or not, that is the way it is.

The `enum` documentation recommends against using value `0` since that is boolean `False` and all members are supposed to be boolean `True`.  The documentation also recommends using this simpler helper function style.
(https://cpython-test-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/enum.html)

To avoid some of these ambiguities the following will behave as documented, and also orders processing to return the most likely results quickly:

```
import enum,os,stat

members= ( \
  ('reg',  'S_ISREG' ), \
  ('dir',  'S_ISDIR' ), \
  ('lnk',  'S_ISLNK' ), \
  ('fifo', 'S_ISFIFO'), \
  ('sock', 'S_ISSOCK'), \
  ('chr',  'S_ISCHR' ), \
  ('blk',  'S_ISBLK' ), \
  ('door', 'S_ISDOOR'), \
  ('port', 'S_ISPORT'), \
  ('wht',  'S_ISWHT' ), \
  ('unimplemented', '') \
  )
FileTypes=enum.Enum('FileTypes',members)

def filetype(path):
  """Get unix filetype:
       reg,dir,lnk,fifo,sock,chr,blk
     and for py3.4+:
       door,port,wht.
    'path' is a full pathname for some file."""
  mode=os.lstat(path).st_mode # do not follow links
  for t in FileTypes:
    try: func=getattr(stat, t.value)
    except AttributeError: continue
    if func(mode): return t
  return FileTypes["unimplemented"]
```

The `enum.ENUM` functional API apparently does not have the sorting bug and keeps the members in the order they are presented, as documented.

Given the troublesome nature of `enum.ENUM`, it is probably better simply to avoid it by using time
tested `python` primitives:

```
import os,stat

_stat_funcs=( \\
  'S_ISREG','S_ISDIR','S_ISLNK','S_ISFIFO','S_ISSOCK', \\
  'S_ISCHR','S_ISBLK','S_ISDOOR','S_ISPORT','S_ISWHT'  )
#                     ^----- python 3.4+ only ----->|
#                     ^-- SOLARIS only --->|^--BSD->|
_ls_chr=( \\
  '-'      ,'d'      ,'l'       ,'p'       ,'s'       , \\
  'c'      ,'b'      ,'D'       ,'P'       ,'w'          )
#                     ^----- python 3.4+ only------>|
#                     ^-- SOLARIS only --->|^--BSD->|
_ftypes=tuple( (c,getattr(stat,f)) \\
    for c,f in zip(_ls_chr,_stat_funcs) if f in dir(stat))

def filetype(path):
  """Get unix filetype designator used in 'ls' shell command listings:
       reg('-'),dir('d'),lnk('l'),fifo('p'),sock('s'),chr('c'),blk('b')
     and for py3.4+:
       door('D'),port('P'),wht('w'). (solaris,solaris,BSD only)
     'path' is a full pathname for some file.    Returns 'u' for an
     unknown or unimplemented filetype."""
  mode=os.lstat(path).st_mode # do not follow links
  for c,func in _ftypes:
    if func(mode): return c
  return 'u'
```

This is a lot more efficient than the code 'Artyer' offers, which is important when processing large numbers of files.  Usage for both `python2` and `3`:

```
>>> filetype('/dev/null') 
'c'
>>> filetype('/dev/sda')
'b'
>>> filetype('/home/test')
'd'
>>> filetype('/home/random.txt')
'-'
>>> filetype('/home/test/hlnk') # hard link
'-'
>>> filetype('/home/test/slnk') # soft link
'l'
>>> filetype('/home/test/sckt')
's'
>>> filetype('/home/test/fifo.pipe')
'p'
>>>
```